# Function to return number of pairs of items within input list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, counting

I'm trying to write a function to count the number of pairs of each color for a given list as input. I've tried to get this output, but I don't know how to identify pairs within the list.

Input:

```
['red','yellow','blue','blue','red','blue']
```

Output:

```
1 pair of red, 1 pair of blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

**Code:**

```
from collections import Counter

def find_pairs(socks):
    c = Counter(socks)
    pairs = dict()
    for k, v in c.items():
        if v >= 2:
            pairs[k] = v//2
    return pairs

socks = ['red','yellow','blue','blue','red','blue']

pairs = find_pairs(socks)

for colour, num_pairs in pairs.items():
    print(f"{num_pairs} pairs of {colour}")
```

**Output:**

```
1 pairs of red
1 pairs of blue
```

Comment: Thanks you very much my dear friend for this help. It means a lot to me. Dear friend, is there any other way to solve this problem without using any built in Module, like here we used collection.counter. I very new to Python. Thanks In advance .